# How could I model this small part of my model?

Tags: modeling

I've been working on an AK-47 model for almost a week now and have almost finished it. However I am for some reason having major difficulties modelling one specific part (Stock tang.)

How would I got about doing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The part that's mostly confusing me is the part where the tang bevels into a round shape and the side parts stop on the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible route:

[image]

In the flat, (under a *Mirror* modifier) sort the topology as much as possible. Insert an extra vertex in the outside diagonal, scale to make rectangular quads.

[image]

Extrude to thickness. When extruding under a Mirror, you have to delete internal faces on the axis. I <kbd>H</kbd> hide a face for access,select one of the faces to go, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> select coplanar, and <kbd>X</kbd> delete.

<kbd>I</kbd> inset the top faces, with 'Boundary' unchecked, laying the foundation for the flange. Cut to correct the mitre on the left to crossed edges, and <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the flange, not all the way round.

[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> Hide all but the top faces of the flange, and use Linear proportional editing to lower the right-hand end.<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> unhide and adjust. Delete screw-hole top and bottom, Bridge Edge  Loops to connect, scale-adjust and maybe extrude bottom at this stage, to block out the countersink.

[image]

If we want an extra edge to round the tapered end of the flange, we can introduce 2 more edge-loops on either side of it. (I made a mistake here, it would have been easier to make 2 on the inside) In order not to disrupt the curvature in the screw-hole, we can introduce another loop around it to accommodate a 3 to 1 'kite' reduction of the loops, top and bottom, before they reach the hole.

[image]

All done bar *Bevel* and *Subdivision*, working under those, to <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> edges to curve the floor-level, <kbd>E</kbd> extrude out the back plates, and tighten things up with some holding loops.

[image]

Comment: While this isnt the exact technique I went with (since it has to be game ready) it really helped with getting a grasp on how all the shapes work and it did also help with how to do the side parts. Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: Ahh, OK.. that makes you a better man than me! Low-poly, much trickier :)